# Is there other way to perform Seam conversation to to handle multiple pageflow in web application?

Tags: seam

I am reading book, Practical JBoss Seam Project. In the page 74, author mentioned "motivation for conversations". The concept is to handle multiple pageflow that user can have different sessions for the same page. For details to click [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=KFAKJoSXkrUC&lpg=PA88&ots=iewN4yeFqK&dq=jboss%20seam%20%2B%20No%20active%20conversation%20context&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=true). I google this idea about conversation but I can't get good answer. My question is if I don't use Seam, is there other way to perform the same result?

Answer (score 0):

> If I do not use Seam, is there other way to perform the same result ?

Short answer: Session attribute

But keep in mind conversation **is handled transparently** in a Seam application. You just especify its boundaries - begin-conversation and end-conversation.